# External Javascript bookmarklet doesn't work

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Its a simple javascript bookmarklet which grabs title,url and selected text. To make sure it grabs the title perfectly(just the title) I had to make this bookmarklet long.It works just fine if i edit the bookamrklet manually.Its way too long to drag and drop just like usual bookmarklet. But i tried a lot through different way to make an external javascript way . I couldn't make it.
I used **google sites** as the hosting site for JS file.

```
     javascript: 
q=(document.location.href);
t=(document.title); 
tt=t.lastIndexOf('|');
if(tt>-1) title=t.substring(0,tt);
else 
{ 
if(t.lastIndexOf('%E2%80%A2')>-1) title=t.substring(0,t.lastIndexOf('%E2%80%A2'));
else if(
t.lastIndexOf('%C2%AB')>-1) title=t.substring(0,t.lastIndexOf('%C2%AB')); 
      else { title=t; } }
if(q.search("inblog")!=-1) 
{ x=title.lastIndexOf('-'); title=title.substring(0,x); }
else if(q.search("m-alo.com")!=-1) 
{ x=title.lastIndexOf('-'); title=title.substring(x+2); }
else if(q.search("blog4")!=-1) 
 { x=title.indexOf('|'); title=title.substring(x+2,title.length); }   
else if(q.search("blogspot")!=-1) 
{ x=title.indexOf(':'); title=title.substring(x+2,title.length); }
else if(q.search("blog")!=-1)          title=document.getElementsByTagName('h2').item(0).innerHTML; 
else if(q.search("arts")!=-1) 
{ x=title.lastIndexOf('%C2%BB'); title=title.substring(x+2); } 
else if(q.search("sports")!=-1||q.search("tech")!=-1)      title=document.getElementsByTagName('h1').item(0).innerHTML;
else if(q.search("blog2")!=-1) { title=document.getElementsByTagName('h1').item(0).innerHTML; x=title.lastIndexOf('">'); title=title.substring(x+4,title.length-4); }
d=document,s=''; 
if(d.getSelection) s=d.getSelection(); if(d.selection) s=d.selection.createRange().text;
if(window.getSelection) s=window.getSelection();
void(open('http://domain.com/submit?url='+encodeURIComponent(q.replace(/[#].*/,''))+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(title)+'&body='+encodeURIComponent(s),'',
'resizable,location,menubar,toolbar,scrollbars,status'));
```

Can you help me? How can i put this script into an external js file and load it?

Answer (score 3):

A bookmarklet usually loads a `<script>` tag which then takes care of doing the rest of the stuff. This reduces the bookmarklet size. Something like:

```
javascript:(function(){

var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://yoursite.com/external.js";
head.appendChild(script);

})();
```

Be sure the edit the "http://yoursite.com/external.js" part.

Comment: javascript:
    (function(){
      var head=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      var script=document.createElement("script");
      script.src="http://sites.google.com/site/Myfile/s3.js";
      head.appendChild(script);
    }
    )();

on my file i just put the above code.
It didn't work!